# How to add another Row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, rows, cells

How can I add another Row
After filling the first row [0]?

```
 public void preencherDTG()
    {
        DTG.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DTG.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = cbModelo.Text;
            DTG.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = txtPlaca.Text;
            DTG.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = txtTotal.Text;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I think you should make like following codes.

```
object [] values = new object [3];
values [0] = cbModello.Text;
values [1] = txtPlaca.Text;
values [2] = txtTotal.Text;

DTG.Rows.Insert (0,values); // insert at first
```